# Which published campaigns that melds D&D and paranoia was my DM talking about?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, product-identification, paranoia

Years ago I was a player in a game that started as a really intense, high action D&D one shot and then within about an hour we learnt that we were in a simulation designed to help us function better as a trouble shooter team. We were playing 3rd or 4th edition D&D but I know our GM at the time used materials from a wide range of sources when creating his campaigns and one-shot adventures.

The effect was made even better by the fact none of us knew we were getting into a Paranoia one-shot. At the time the GM said he had taken the idea from *a published campaign* but I can’t find what that might have been.

I know that there is an old adventure Alice through the mirror shades that melds together Paranoia and Cyberpunk.

Is there anything similar for D&D or any other role play system?

I will say that our group loves it when I throw together a Paranoia adventure for them. My printer not so much, so many forms to print off.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Orcbusters](https://www.drivethrurpg.com/product/224395/Orcbusters) is a classic Paranoia 1e adventure that involves wizards crossing over into Alpha Complex and, eventually, the Troubleshooters getting dumped into a fantasy adventure setting.

Likewise, there is [Call of Computer](http://www.sjgames.com/pyramid/sample.html?id=22), which crosses Paranoia with Cthulhu. It was published in *Pyramid*, not by West End Games.

Lastly, there is the absolutely awful [Creatures of the Nightcycle](https://www.rpggeek.com/rpgitem/61154/creatures-nightcycle) for Paranoia 5th un-Edition that attempts to parody Vampire: The Masquerade. Do not bother with it.